# ggplot2 changing fill colors of geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make bar charts using manual fill color. Right now I have the 5 default colors for the 5 columns. I would like to keep using 5 distinct colors but manually specified. I tried the `scale_color_manual` option but it does not do the job. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

[image: Example image here]

```
  mycolors <- c("#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D")
  sub_terms %>% 
    mutate(term=reorder_within(term, beta, topic)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(term, beta, fill = factor(topic))) +
    geom_col(show.legend = F) +
    scale_color_manual(values=mycolors) +
    facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free", nrow=1) +
    coord_flip()+
    scale_x_reordered()
```

Comment: `scale_color_manual` will map to the `color` aesthetic whereas you are using `fill` for shading by topic.  Use `scale_fill_manual` instead.  Note that it would be helpful if you could post a sample of you `sub_terms` data frame to make the question reproducible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3277821).

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in a comment to your post, you need to change the scale from `color` to `fill`.

Color and fill are distinct different aesthetics, that you can control separately. So when you assign `fill` you need to scale with `scale_fill_manual` too.

```
  mycolors <- c("#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D")
  sub_terms %>% 
    mutate(term=reorder_within(term, beta, topic)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(term, beta, fill = factor(topic))) +
    geom_col(show.legend = F) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors) +
    facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free", nrow=1) +
    coord_flip()+
    scale_x_reordered()
```